# GET request using fetch() failing why?

Tags: javascript, get, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from datamuse api using a fetch get request in JS but everytime i go to test the request in the chrome console i get 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' would anyone know why this is. i am using python to host the webpage on a localhost server as such: 
[python server hosting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA9jD.png)

my code for the request can be seen below. thanks!

```javascript
//GET request
const getRhymes = async () => {
  const wordQuery = input.value;
  const endpoint = `${url}${queryParams}${wordQuery}`;

  console.log(`The endpoint is: ${endpoint}`);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      renderJsonResponse(jsonResponse);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you please give more context? What are the values of your params?

Comment: of course. the url and query params are as such:const url = "https://api.datamuse.com/words?";
const queryParams = "rel_rhy=";

const input = document.querySelector("#textInput");
const submit = document.querySelector("#searchButton");
const output = document.querySelector("#responseField");
the word query is just a word that has been entered into an input text box in the webpage

Comment: If you go to network tab in browser, what does your request look like?

Comment: i have managed to fix it myself. the issue didnt seem to be with any of my code it was the api that couldnt handle the word i was querying to test it. thank you though!